# A file save via notepadd++ is failing diff comparison on terminal

Tags: windows, unix, character-encoding, diff, notepad++

I saved a text file both in UTF-8 and ASCII using notepad++ on windows. The text, which had the same letter representation as the UNIX version, were claimed to be completely different by diff (e.g. 1,267c1,267). The files were actually different on binary level (xxd -b test.txt), but then vimdiff had different result than vim: it showed them to be identical. I am guessing because vimdiff renders the text before doing diff on files? Why is there such inconsistency?

Comment: This difference is what I've learned to call 'working according to specification'. I would expect files saved as UTF-8 and ASCII to generate differences. Aren' UTF-8 chars 2 bytes wide, while ASCII chars 1 byte? There's probably a perl, php or python modules that can deal with this issue, but I don't have any experience to share. Sorry, and Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `-b` option to `diff`, it will ignore leading and trailing whitespace, including differences in end-of-line characters. If this doesn't take care of the problem, you can do a closer inspection of the individual files with `hd` (hexdump) or `od -c` (Octal dump, showing ascii characters).

Answer (score 0):

Check end-of-line characters in the files you compare. It might be that you've saved them with `\r\n` at the end of each line while the Unix versions were terminated with `\n`.

Comment: vimdiff detects such differences by denoting \r\n as ^M on the buffer.